# Are keys required for values in redux actions?

Tags: redux

The [redux docs (under basics > actions)](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) use this as their example for an action:

> `{
>     type: ADD_TODO,
>     text: 'Build my first Redux app'
>   }`

yet they use this as their example for an action creator:

> `function addTodo(text) {
>     return {
>       type: ADD_TODO,
>       text
>     }
>   }`

In the first example every value in the action object has an associated key (`type` and `text`) however, **what is the difference between this and the second example in which the action only specifies the key for `type` and just includes the value of the parameter in the action?** and when should each method be used?

Also, does this second method just mean that the variable name is used as a key? If so, can you do for multiple different variables in the same action creator?

**EDIT**: apologies for the ambiguity. Essentially what I am wondering is the difference between the two action objects, not about action vs action creator.

AKA this

```
function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text
    }
}
```

versus

```
function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    data: text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd example shows an example of using an action creator to generate the action in the first example.

Action creators carry the same benefits of using a function for generating an object in general, namely that you reduce redundancy and can easily modify the action type or payload in one place in the future.

For that reason it's common in Redux to see the pattern:

```
dispatch(addTodo('Do laundry'));
```

As opposed to:

```
dispatch({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  text: 'Do laundry',
});
```

Although they are identical in their result.

Edit after updated question:

The 2nd example uses [es6 shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to define the `text` key. So `{text}` is identical to `{text: text}`.

Comment: Thanks for your well-written answer! However, i have already learned the magical ways of the action creator thanks to the redux docs. I was primarily wondering if you need to specify a key for every action in an action creator or if you can just use a parameter/variable and what the difference is between these methods of writing action creators. I've updated my question to make this more clear.

Comment: You can use any key you want in your action. It's just a convention to use `type` and `payload`. It all depends on how you want to handle the action in your reducer.

Comment: so does not specifying one (such as in the second to last code block in the question) make it default to `payload`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not specifying one"? The 2nd to last code block specifies 2 keys: `type` and `text`. Text is defined using es6 shorthand.

Comment: And there is no "default" key included in actions. The action given to the reducer will only contain what you define.

Comment: Oh ok. So that second to last block's `text` variable automatically expands to (or is identical to) `text: text` because of es6?

Comment: Yep! You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). You'll see a lot of es6 in Redux docs, which can be confusing at first if you're not used to it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I only recently started react-native so im not quite used to all of these things yet haha. Could you maybe edit your answer to include a short explanation of the es6 shorthand so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Updated. Thanks! I remember this tripped me up too when learning Redux. I'd also recommend getting comfortable with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which is used frequently.

Comment: i was literally just messing with that as you sent that haha. Thanks for the info.